# target="_blank" link opening in PWA and not in browser in Android

Tags: android, google-chrome, progressive-web-apps

I have a website which is also a PWA.

If I add the PWA to my device (Android) and then go back into the browser (Chrome, latest available version for Android), the links with `target="_blank"` will open in the PWA, no matter what.

I know this could be a corner case, but what if I want to be sure that browsers links will be open in browser and not in the PWA?

iOS behaves correctly...

Comment: Just curious. Why build a PWA if you want some pages of that PWA to open in the normal browser window (not in the existing standalone PWA)? Also: Are you using router links to get to these pages? A code snipet may help us figure it out.

Comment: @Mathias good question. But the answer is sadly: "they told me to do so".

Comment: Been there done that  :-)

Comment: @Mathias: E.g. to have your application run in fullscreen mode, but the linked PDF with instructions for use in the browser, because otherwise there's just no way in navigating "back" from the PDF

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In manifest.json you set a scope, which determines which links will open in the PWA and which will open in the browser:

[scope parameter in PWA Manifest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest/scope)

Edit: Explanation as well as examples are right on the page linked above.... But I can paste them here for you, if that helps?

> The scope member is a string that defines the navigation scope of this web application's application context. It restricts what web pages can be viewed while the manifest is applied. **If the user navigates outside the scope, it reverts to a normal web page inside a browser tab or window.**
> If the scope is a relative URL, the base URL will be the URL of the manifest.

Relative Scope: "scope": "/app/"
Limiting Scope to Domain: "scope": "https://example.com/"
Combining the above examples: "scope": "https://example.com/subdirectory/"

Comment: Can you give an example, please? Can`t find any documentation on how to do this in the manifest scope parameter. Also, I have multiple URLs which should be opened in the browser.

Comment: I have it set to "./" and it does not work for me. Is it supposed to be something else?

Comment: So if you want to call `window.open` for a specific link in your site, your entire has to be move to a subpath?

Comment: Same as @DmitryEfimenko , not working for me - the links I open are third party websites.