# how to open link from pwa(in android shell) to another browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple pwa app running in an android shell.
Whenever I click on a link, it opens the url in the android browser shell.
How can I make it open in another browser?

What I already tried so far:

- target _blank,
- target _system,
- "external:https://somelink.com"

The following snippet doesn't work either:

```
openlLink = (link) =>{
    window.open(link,'My Page',500,500);
  }
```

The desired result is to open the link in any other standalone browser, instead of the webview.

Comment: probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/53458511/5801946

Comment: Possible duplicate of [target="\_blank" link opening in PWA and not in browser in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53173797/target-blank-link-opening-in-pwa-and-not-in-browser-in-android)