# Links with target=_blank opens in browser

Tags: progressive-web-apps

In my PWA website, I have in a few places, links that open in new tab using `target="_blank"`. I want to maintain this functionality but not if the user has installed the PWA.

Currently, if the user installs the PWA and click on that link, the user is taken to the browser and the page loads there.

I have tried all different kinds of scope but all give same result.

```
/
./
https://beta.domain.com/
```

Comment: What functionality do you want when the user has the PWA installed? I'm guessing you can just have a function that checks if the user has the PWA installed, and if they do replace all target="_blank" instances in the HTML with the target you want.

Comment: That would solve the problem. Is the PWA correct in its behavior? Do _blank links are supposed to open in browser even though they are on the same domain (scope)?

Comment: Yes, if you have the target set as _blank then it will always open the link in a new tab in the browser, even if the link is for the same domain.

Comment: This is a tough thing to implement. Not all _blank links needs to stay within PWA. External links do make sense to open in browser. I guess I'll have to check the domain of the URL as well. I hope they give more control over this in the future, maybe with the `capture_links` directive.

Comment: agreed, but I’m afraid I can’t help you out much more than that since I don’t know the context of your app.

Comment: I'll make it work but just for context, the page is product listing page of an ecommerce site. Each product when clicked opens in a new tab like amazon, standard stuff.

Comment: `_blank` default behavior is to open in a new browser tab. PWA apps are still using your default installed browser to compile and run the application, so when you click a _blank targeted link, the browser will just do what it is told - open a new tab.

Comment: I understand that. But this behaviour was implemented before PWA's existed. What I'm saying is its not the desired behaviour in most cases IMO and should either be changed (for PWA only) or given a control over it.

Comment: Hi ! As far as I can understand, the opposite behavior seems to be described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53173797/4698373), and the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53458511/4698373) talks about the `scope` in the `manifest` file.
I hope this helps ! :)

Comment: Yeah. I can reproduce that on Android. If I click the _blank link in broswer it opens the app. If I click the same link in the app, it opens the browser (web view). The PWA people needs to work on `target`'s behavior.

Comment: Ok. So, I see no other workaround than replacing the relevant links from `_blank` to `_self`. Would it match your goal ?

Comment: Yeah that's a bandaid fix for now. It is what I'm using currently as @Jasper suggested

Answer (score 1):

```
// Add this script after </body>
<script>
if (window.matchMedia('(display-mode: standalone)').matches) { 
  // if webapp installed, remove 'target' attribute of links
  document.querySelectorAll('a[target=_blank]').forEach(function(a) {
     a.removeAttribute('target');
  });
}
</script>
```